# Custom User Authentication using DRF

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

Want to create a Web RESTful API with Django. For that I'm using [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

What are the necessary steps to get the authentication using a custom User model (subclassing **AbstractBaseUser**) exposing the endpoints to be used?

Comment: You might find a lot of resources to get more precise ideas here : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/api-clients/#authentication

Comment: @TimothéDelion the reason I didn't specify too much is because not only the docs don't share too much info about this but also because then it becomes more of the same types of questions associated with Django. I see potential in this question and it's answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Create a Custom User Model

The documentation is good when it comes to [Specifying a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model).

In our models.py, import [AbstractBaseUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser) and [BaseUserManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager).

Then, create your class, for instances,

```
class Profiles(AbstractBaseUser):
    userId = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique= True)
    username = models.CharField(max_lenght=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_lenght=256)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

Here it's very important to set [USERNAME_FIELD](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD) and [REQUIRED_FIELDS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.REQUIRED_FIELDS) to define which fields are important when logging in.

Also in your custom user model class, you have to create two functions needed to deal with permissions, namely [has_perm()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm) and [has_module_perms()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_module_perms).

---

### 2. Create a Custom User Manager

Now the next step is to create a [Custom User Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-a-manager-for-a-custom-user-model), which is something recommended by Django.

So we create a class like

```
class ProfilesManager(BaseUserManager):
    ...
```

In that class, one needs to override two methods, namely [create_user()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) and [create_superuser()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_superuser), to define what happens when a user is created and when a superuser is created, respectively.

Then, we need to tell Profiles class with an objects parameter where this ProfilesManager class is.

```
class Profiles(AbstractBaseUser):
    userId = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique= True)
    email = models.CharField(max_lenght=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_lenght=256)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...

    USERNAME_FIELDS = 'userId'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    objects = ProfilesManager()

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

---

### 3. Set User Model

Go to your settings.py and add a [AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) property, specifying which user model Django should use.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'appName.Profiles'
```

---

### 4. Make migrations

To commit the changes made above one has to [make the migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/) by running

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

---

### 5. Register User from REST API

As we have created the model, then we just need to create the [serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/), [views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) and urls.